# How to force SSL on all FTP connections on a VPS Windows Server 2018

Tags: ssl, iis, ftp, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I have a VPS server that is running on Windows Server 2016. I added FTP access to one site on that VPS. But every time the user tries to connect using FileZilla FTP the user is prompted with the following.

[image]

I think I am forcing all FTP connection to use SSL but not positive.

In IIS Manager, I selected the site I want to force SSL on from the left tree. Then I selected "FTP SSL Settings" as you see in the picture below

[image]

Then I selected "Require SSL connections" and selected the SSL certificate that is used by that site.

How can I solve this problem and force all connections to use a secure connection?

Comment: It is more common to open FTP over SSL service at port 990 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS

Comment: @LexLi I have changed port 21 to 990 but I am no longer able to connect.